AWS Glue Not Fetching Full Dataset While Job Run
I have build a job using SQL Server as data source and it all works fine in the Data Preview.
But when I run the job it works with only the dataset that has been pulled in the Data Preview and doesn't pick anything else from the SQL Server db.
Any idea how to debug and resolve it ?
Script of the Visual ETL :
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrameCollection
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)

# Script generated for node Custom Transform
def MyTransform(glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    dynamic_frame = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0])
    spark_df = dynamic_frame.toDF()
    spark_df.write.format("iceberg").mode("append").save("MyCatalog.MyDatabase.MyTable")

    return DynamicFrameCollection({"default": DynamicFrame.fromDF(spark_df, glueContext, "default")}, glueContext)

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Script generated for node Microsoft SQL Server
MicrosoftSQLServer_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "sqlserver",
    connection_options = {
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "dbo.MyTableName",
        "connectionName": "MyConnectionName",
    },
    transformation_ctx = "MicrosoftSQLServer_node"
)

# Script generated for node SQL Query
SqlQuery0 = '''My SQL Query'''
SQLQuery_node = sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query = SqlQuery0, mapping = {"myDataSource":MicrosoftSQLServer_node}, transformation_ctx = "SQLQuery_node")

# Script generated for node Custom Transform
CustomTransform_node = MyTransform(glueContext, DynamicFrameCollection({"SQLQuery_node": SQLQuery_node}, glueContext))

job.commit()

Here are my Job Parameters :
--conf        spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions 
 --conf        spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog 
 --conf        spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse=MyS3WareHouse
 --conf        spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog 
 --conf        spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO 
 --conf        spark.sql.iceberg.handle-timestamp-without-timezone=true 

It is expected to fetch records from my On Prem DB Server and write to the Iceberg table I have on my aws S3.
